# Why do I have Apple certificates in my keychain?

Tags: keychain

Today, i looked over my `keychain` and was surprised to find out that i have several apple certificates as part of it. I wonder .. what is the significance of them and how could i have possibly gotten them? (I am not a registered apple developer)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X ships with at least two apple root CA and several intermediate certificates installed.  They are used to verify things like software updates.

You can find them published on apple.com at the url below.

https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/